# Add sortable columns to Data Explorer's query results

Tags: feature-request, sorting, data-explorer

Column headers on query results should sort the results when clicked

Comment: I like this request, it just requires a little bit of extra coding, also ie can be really slow at sorting so I need to be extra careful

Answer (score 7):

I [added support for this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/19) for tables with <= 5000 results (as a quick n' dirty way to handle IE's less-than-optimal performance here), pending a pull and redeploy of Data Explorer.

The sorting is very basic and single-column to start with, but if more advanced use cases come up it could be expanded as necessary.

Comment: This is working well for normal columns, but smart links are sorting randomly. E.g. [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205985/who-favorited-me?UserId=256431) clicking on the actual Ids do group the queries or users, but clicking on the smart link columns order "interestingly".

Comment: Yeah, that's already fixed in a to-be-deployed changeset ([commit](https://github.com/tms/StackExchange.DataExplorer/commit/ecf6d89bf4841d5f1af59bc6f829a09d44a7cec4)).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is necessary since the Data Explorer simply runs SQL queries... You can just add/modify an `ORDER BY` clause to do this, and that's far more powerful than simple visible column sorting anyway.

Comment: That means re-submitting the query to the server, which is often less desirable.