# Why can't I sort SEDE results for some queries?

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer, sorting

I was just checking out who earned the most of the [new badges that were announced this week](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/). I have a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide) for this which sorts by default on the number of sites you earned a badge. I noticed that when I run it for the harder badge, [Lifeboat](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Lifeboat) (awarded to 1089 users on the network), I can click on the column headers to change the sorting:

[image]

However, for [Lifejacket](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/748298/holders-of-a-specific-badge-networkwide?badgename=Lifeboat), awarded to 10104 users (which is less than SEDE's maximum of 50000), sorting the results doesn't work:

[image]

<sub>(I am aware that I can just change the `ORDER BY` in the final `SELECT` statement, but then I need to maintain two queries. Also, I can make the sorting depend on another parameter, but I'm too lazy ...)</sub>

@rene points out in the comments that it's a [deliberate choice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213422/295232) and blindly increasing this number may still lead to performance problems with 2019's browsers. Therefore, it's now a formal [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to redesign the grid (or implement another library) so that sorting is always possible.

Comment: Sort is disabled for resultsets with more then 5000 rows. This is a limitation of the used grid control.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307608/158100

Comment: And I guess that there's no simple way to crank that up to 50,000, since somebody would've already done that?

Comment: Here is the original implementation answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/add-sortable-columns-to-data-explorers-query-results/213422#213422

Comment: We could crank it up but we might crank down every reasonable browser who views a resultset. Your call ....

Comment: Internet Explorer (at least the version that existed back in 2013) does not fall under my definition of 'reasonable browser'.

Comment: well, let me run an experiment in the next 6 to 8 days to see if this limitation is no longer an issue. But that has to wait a bit as I'm not near a dev-box that has a local running SEDE.

Comment: Okay, the setting is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/df52cec7183fdcaa221e51110bb7e033019a837e/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.resultset.js#L20) and I have done an experiment with 32000 rows. There is a considerable lag / hang when the 32000 rows are added to the DOM. Think in the order of 5 to 10 seconds in IE11. After that sorting is smooth and quick. Just the initial load is suboptimal.

Comment: At this moment I think ramping up that value to 50000 is not a good call. This needs an overhaul of that grid to address this and a couple of other issues.